# It is bad form to radically change question titles if the original one was useless?

Tags: discussion

Would it be considered bad form to completely change the title of a question if the original title is essentially worthless? Specifically I'm thinking about [curious chess situation](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3379/curious-chess-situation). A much better question title (in my opinion) is the question content.

I just wasn't sure if a complete title change would be considered out-of-bounds and didn't want to do it without asking the community.

Comment: Edit away, the OP can always roll it back if it displeases him/her.

Answer (score 6):

It is very *good* form to completely change the title if it improves the question!

We <3 editing here, so as long as you can make a reasonable case that your edit makes the post better, go for it!

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/